# SQL Server: Selecting rows based on multiple conditions within the same unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to select rows in an SQL table based on multiple conditions within the same unique ID.

I have the following table:

ID       Status
1         AS
2         Rec
2         AS

The rules are as follows:

- If an [ID] has both 'Rec' and 'AS', select only the row with 'Rec'. In other words, 'Rec' has precedence over 'AS'.
- If the [ID] does not have 'Rec', select the row with 'AS'.

I want the query to output only the rows `ID=1,Status=AS` and `ID=2,Status=Rec`.

What is the query to select **only** these two rows?

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a helper column or field that serves as an order for your values?

```
Rec = 3
AS = 2
....
```

Then, see the description and related article here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129703/5819421

The article talks of "Selecting the one maximum row from each group" which sounds like how this would work for you.

Comment: I cannot create additional columns. It would be easy if I could simply add a `WHERE [newCol] = 'whatever'` condition but I do not have control over this.

Answer (score 1):

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY status DESC) rn, ID, Status
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id, status 
        FROM MyTable
    )--in case you have several Rec's and AS's
)
SELECT id, status
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Of course there may be a need to further filter the derived table in the CTE if there are also other status values that you don't want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Status
FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = 'Rec'
OR (
 Status = 'AS'
 AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Status='Rec', correlated to outer query on Id
 )
)
```

In English, get a distinct set of rows where Status is "Rec" or where status is "AS" and there's no "Rec" for the same Id.